# Repairing a Dell XPS 13 (9333) loose display hinge

Tags: hardware-rec, dell-xps, laptop-display

I have a **Dell XPS 13 (9333) model** and the **display hinge** is very loose. I've already tried tightening the hinges but that didn't help the problem.

Does anyone have any fix tips for this problem, or could someone recommend an action I should take to repair it myself?

I wasn't sure if I should look for a repair manual somewhere to read up on it, and where I'd order the replacement parts.

I'm not sure if I could buy just the display hinge or if I have to buy an entire assembly bundle to get just the parts I need.

EDIT:
I'm really sorry for necroposting, but this was the problem I was talking about. Has anyone else had this kind of defect?
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19453039

Comment: You need to describe "loose", your attempted repair, and the result.  Does the hinge, itself have excessive play, or is it that it doesn't remain securely fastened?  What did you do to repair it and what was the result?

Comment: This link better describes the problem I have (someone else also had this problem) http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19453039

Answer (score 1):

> **Dell XPS 13 (9333) display hinge is loose**
>
> I already tried tightening the hinges but that didn't do anything. Has
>   anyone else had this error, and if you fixed it, how did you fix it?

For the **display hinge** replacement procedure, I suggest the recommendations as per the [XPS Owners Manual](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_xps_laptop/xps-13-9333_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf) on **pages 41-44** going over the **Display Assembly** removal and replacement procedures which includes the **display hinges**.

To order the applicable part needed in your case (display hinges), I would suggest contacting Dell Sales directly via [Chat, Phone, or Email](http://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/19/campaigns/chat-splitter-us?~ck=pn) and asking them what you need to purchase, the cost, the cost of them to replace it for you, and so forth.

> ### Removing the Display Assembly
>
> ***WARNING: Before working inside your computer, read the safety information that shipped with your computer and follow the steps in
>   "Before Working Inside Your Computer" on page 7. After working inside
>   your computer, follow the instructions in "After Working Inside Your
>   Computer" on page 9. For more safety best practices, see the
>   Regulatory Compliance home page at dell.com/regulatory_compliance.***
>
> **Prerequisites**
>
> 1. Remove the base cover. See "Removing the Base Cover" on page 10.
> 2. Disconnect the power-light board cable from the system board. See "Removing  the Power-Light Board" on page 12.
> 3. Remove the battery. See "Removing the Battery" on page 14
>
> **Procedure**
>
> 1. Disconnect the display cable from the system board
>
>    [image]
> 2. Disconnect the wireless-card cables from the connectors on the wireless card.
> 3. Disconnect the touchscreen cable from the system board.
> 4. Lift the connector latch and using the pull-tab, disconnect the touchpad cable from the system board.
> 5. Release the wireless-card cables from the routing guides.
>
>    [image]
> 6. Remove the screws that secure the display assembly to the palm-rest assembly.
> 7. Gently lift the palm-rest assembly to a 90-degree angle and then release the palm-rest assembly off the display assembly.
>
>    [image]
>
> ### Replacing the Display Assembly
>
> ***WARNING: Before working inside your computer, read the safety information that shipped with your computer and follow the steps in
>   "Before Working Inside Your Computer" on page 7. After working inside
>   your computer, follow the instructions in "After Working Inside Your
>   Computer" on page 9. For more safety best practices, see the
>   Regulatory Compliance home page at dell.com/regulatory_compliance.***
>
> **Procedure**
>
> 1. Slide and place the palm-rest assembly over the display assembly.
> 2. Press down on the display hinges and align the screw holes on the display hinges with the screw holes on the palm-rest assembly.
> 3. Replace the screws that secure the display assembly to the palm-rest assembly.
> 4. Route the wireless-card cables through the routing guides.
> 5. Slide the touchpad cable into the touchpad-cable connector on the system board and press down on the connector latch to secure the
>      keyboard cable.
> 6. Connect the wireless-card cables to the connectors on the wireless card. The following table provides the wireless-card cable color
>      scheme for the wireless card supported by your computer.
>
> **Connectors on the Wireless Card:**
>
> - WLAN + Bluetooth (2 cables)
> - Main WLAN + Bluetooth (white triangle)
>
>   - **Wireless-Card Cable Color Scheme:** white
> - Auxiliary WLAN + Bluetooth (black triangle)
>
>   - **Wireless-Card Cable Color Scheme:** black
>
> **Postrequisites**
>
> 1. Replace the battery. See "Replacing the Battery" on page 15.
> 2. Connect the power-light board cable to the system board. See "Replacing the Power-Light Board" on page 13.
> 3. Replace the base cover. See "Replacing the Base Cover" on page 11.
>
> <sub>[source](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_xps_laptop/xps-13-9333_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf)</sub>

Comment: Wait so am I taking out the display and putting it back in again?

Comment: @BrianLee Not necessarily, the display hinge replacement procedure is however documented in with the display assembly procedure from the repair manual. I'd give Dell a call, ask them the specific questions for what parts you need to buy to get the hinges so you have a better idea what you'll need to purchase exactly. U could then compare the pricing of buying it to do yourself or ask how much to ship it to them for them to repair it and ship it back -- they'd likely send U a shipping box too. If U reach out to Dell as I suggested as well, they can answer the specific questions most accurately.

Answer (score 0):

How did you tighten the hinges? Did you notice any breakage in the plastic surrounding the screw molds? That seems to actually be the most common reason displays becomes loose.

Comment: Screw molds? What are those? Although come to think of it, I paid more attention in tightening the screws straight-up. I'll probably take another look at it

Comment: Ok, so you didn't open the laptop up then, correct?
The part the screws go in to to keep the hinges in place is essentially a part of the rest of the case. if that broke, you could tighten those screws all day but they aren't going to hold to the rest of the computer. It seems to me that's what you might be looking at in your situation.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Your answer is more suitable as a comment. Pleas refrain from posting comments as if they were answers, until you have the minimum reputation necessary to post comments.